# Compute $\operatorname{Tor}_n^R(I,R/I)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

The problem is as follows:

> Let $I=\langle x^2,y\rangle\subset R=\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$. Compute $\operatorname{Tor}_n^R(I,R/I)$ for all $n\geq 0$.

Thoughts:

Usually when I see these types of problems, I consider a SES of the form(s):

$0\rightarrow I\rightarrow R\rightarrow R/I\rightarrow 0$
or

$0\rightarrow R\rightarrow R\rightarrow R/I\rightarrow 0$ where the first map in the last SES would be multiplication by an appropriate factor.

The first SES does not seem promising in our case, since it boils down to computing $\operatorname{Tor}_n^R(I,I)$, which I don't see any immediate ways of doing.

To use the second SES I was thinking of letting $f:R\rightarrow R$ be such that $x\rightarrow x^2$ and $y\rightarrow y$.

I'm not sure if this would work?

Comment: Another possibility is to try to construct an explicit free resolution of $R/I$.

Comment: True! I was also thinking of using the basic definition of Tor, by constructing a projective resolution, but that is usually messy, and not so easy to do! Is there an easy projective resolution of $R/I?$

Comment: Just a point...if you were able to construct the second SES then that would be a free resolution. You really aren't asking for more it seems.

Comment: Yes! If i can construct the second SES I can go from there!

Comment: @YACP: As it is, It is wrong, but I'm saying if I could construct the second SES then the rest of the problem is not difficult!

Comment: Use the first SES, and tensor with R/I. Note that any module $M$ tensored with $R/I$ is just $M/IM $.

Comment: @YACP: I'll try that!

Comment: @SteveD: Tensoring with R/I, i still run into a similar problem as tensoring with I.

Answer (score 1):

First of all we can see that $I$ is given by regular elements. Therefore there exists a Koszul-resolution of $R/I$ given by

$$A^{\bullet}=0\rightarrow R\rightarrow R^2\rightarrow R\rightarrow 0,$$

where the first non-trivial map is $1\rightarrow (x^2,-y)$, and the second is $(a,b)\rightarrow ay+bx^2$.

You take now $I\otimes A^{\bullet}=I\rightarrow I^2\rightarrow I$.
You see that there are three possible non-zero $\operatorname{Tor}$s.

You know what $\operatorname{Tor}_0^R(I,R/I)$ is.

Let's see $\operatorname{Tor}_1^R(I,R/I)$. The kernel of $I^2\rightarrow I$ can be computed by looking at $(a,b)\rightarrow ay+bx^2$. In order to this holds we need that $a=x^2c$ and $b=-yc$. So the kernel is isomorphic to $R$. The image of $I\rightarrow I^2$ is $I$ in $R$ (we identifiy now the kernel with $R$), so $\operatorname{Tor}_1^R(I,R/I)=R/I$.

Finally, the map $I\rightarrow I^2$ is injective, therefore $\operatorname{Tor}_2^R(I,R/I)=0$.